# "Où en est ton français ?"

Tags: grammaire

J'ai vu cette phrase quelque part sur le web comme traduction de la phrase anglaise "How is your French coming along?"

Mais je ne comprends pas la grammaire là-dedans...pourquoi est-ce que ces mots marche dan cet ordre ? "Where in is your French?"

Comment: *Where at is your French?* would be more like it...